# Is there a reason why we might use a function over an href tag?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

I am working on a project and have been shown a method where we use a function to open a new window. The code looks like this:

Javascript:

```
function createWindow() {
let url = "https://google.com";
let win = window.open(url, "My New Window", "width=300, height=200");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    win.name + " - " + win.opener.location;
}

let h = window.outerHeight
let w = window.outerWidth
window.document.write("Height and width of the window are: " + h + " and " + w)
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Click to open a new Window:</h3>
<button onclick="createWindow()">Open a Window</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

is there a reason why we would use this over using a button with an anchor tag and a target tab?

Comment: yes, ... how would you do `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    win.name + " - " + win.opener.location;` and set the window dimensions in  HTML only?

Comment: Well for starters, in your own example you are setting the width/height of the window with javascript. How would you do that with a anchor tag?

Comment: I would think you could set the width an height using styling in the HTML, or set a class and style in css

Comment: You can’t, so that’d be why. (Setting window sizes isn’t really done these days, though. Opening windows is also rare.)